# Python Recursion in Class

Tags: python

This program will validate the Parentheses, which is correctly closed or not..This program working good in method..(in below)

```
def validParameters(s):
    s = s.replace(" ",'')
    comp = ['{}','[]','()']
    if len(s) == 0:
        return True

    for i,j in zip(s,s[1:]):
        if i+j in comp:
            base = s.replace(i,'')
            base = base.replace(j,'')
            return validParameters(base)
        else:
            pass
    return False
```

but by using class I get an error of "NameError: name 'validParameters' is not defined"

```
class Solution:
    def validParameters(self, s: str) -> bool:
        if ' ' in s:
            s = s.replace(" ",'')
        comp = ['{}','[]','()']
        if len(s) == 0:
            return True

        for i,j in zip(s,s[1:]):
            if i+j in comp:
                base = s.replace(i,'')
                base = base.replace(j,'')
                return validParameters(base)
            else:
                pass
        return False
```

I'm new to class in python can anyone explain me, how to correct this error?

Comment: use `self.validParameters(base)`, remember dealing with classes and calling internal method  use `self` with them

Comment: Thank you..!! SO much...

Comment: Note that defining a class solely to wrap what would otherwise work just as well as an ordinary function is not common practice.

Answer (score 0):

`validParameters()` is a method of your class, and so when accessing it from inside a method, you've to use the `self` keyword like so

```
self.validParameters(base)
```